# Reference error: ngI18nClosureMode is not defined

Tags: angular, deployment

I tried to deploy my Angular 7 web application and it throws an error - Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: ngI18nClosureMode is not defined.

The application works fine when run locally.

Did anyone come across this kind of error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This happens mainly because of the inconsistency in package versions. Since you downgraded all versions to match `8.0.0`, the issue was resolved.
I encountered the same problem, where my `angular-cli` version was `8.2.1` and others were set to `8.2.7`. Changing everything to `8.2.7` resolved the issue.

Another possibility is that you might encounter `No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'` issue. This is another one of the problems caused by inconsistency in versions.

Hope this comes handy for you in future.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting it incase it might be useful for others - I was able to resolve this issue by downgrading all my @angular/* packages to 8.0.0 and rebuilding.