# exports is not defined error in angular 8

Tags: angular

I have created a JSON config that has been added to my angular 8 project. Ever since I have made changes in the way the config is imported in the project, I get error when trying to serve the project in prod mode. I am getting error exports is not defined.
Not sure why it complains in prod mode and runs fine in dev mode.

Error

[image]

Following is my code changes

If you notice I have added the following two lines of code in tsconfig

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
 "esModuleInterop": true
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "module": "UMD",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    } 
}
```

config.json

```
{
    "settings": {
        "production": false,
        "userIdleMinutes": "10",
        "corePingIntervalSeconds": "10",
        "baseUrl": "http://localhost:57973",
        "loginUrl": "/Login",
        "adminUrl": "/Admin"
    }
}
```

This is the way it has been imported in the enviornment.ts

enviornment.ts

```
import config from '../assets/config.json'

// The file contents for the current environment will overwrite these during build.
// The build system defaults to the dev environment which uses `environment.ts`, but if you do
// `ng build --env=prod` then `environment.prod.ts` will be used instead.
// The list of which env maps to which file can be found in `.angular-cli.json`.

export const environment = {
    production: config.settings.production,
    baseUrl: config.settings.baseUrl,
    loginUrl:config.settings.loginUrl,
    adminUrl: config.settings.adminUrl,
    userIdleMinutes: config.settings.userIdleMinutes,
    corePingIntervalSeconds: config.settings.corePingIntervalSeconds 
};
```

Comment: Try to enable source maps to be able to see a human readable stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Change your compiler options to something like,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "umd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: YOu have removed    "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true . The main purpose to include that in the first place was for the ability to import json files

Comment: you can add them back, i just wnated to show that you need to have "module":umd

Comment: so isnt my module umd in my post ?

Comment: that should come under compilerOptions

Comment: isnt it under compiler options :) . I anyways moved it above but the error persist

Comment: yes. I had specifically changed it to lowercase and checked

Answer (score 0):

These errors happen mostly because there is a mismatch in your package versions that are being used. ie., `angular-core` package version wouldn't be compatible with any of your packages. Do take a look in the individual package's npm repo.
There are similar errors which can often occur when your angular application uses local dependencies instead of the ones you have specified in your `package.json`.
Run `ng v` to get all the versions that are currently being in use and compare them with the ones you have specified in your package file.
Do take a look at this question. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898373/reference-error-ngi18nclosuremode-is-not-defined/58026539#58026539)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Based on the following comment from Tom, will my original answer not work for him.

> I need it to be JSON is because the Octopus deployment tool can read JSON files

But then changing the config import in the enviornment file, should do the trick. The reason way the asterisk sign is needed, is because you are not exporting a module from the json file. By adding the asterisk sign, you are telling typescript that the content is the module.

**enviornment.ts**

```js
 import * as config from "../assets/config.json";
```

---

**Original Post**

Since you are importing the config at the compilation time, the easy fix would be to change the config.json file to a config.ts file. Then defining the config in a variable.

This is only a possible solution, if it is not a requirement that the config is in a .json file.

**config.ts**

```js
    export const config = {
      "settings": {
        "production": false,
        "userIdleMinutes": "10",
        "corePingIntervalSeconds": "10",
        "baseUrl": "http://localhost:57973",
        "loginUrl": "/Login",
        "adminUrl": "/Admin"
      }
    }
```

**enviornment.ts**

```js
    import { config } from '../assets/config'

    // The file contents for the current environment will overwrite these during build.
    // The build system defaults to the dev environment which uses `environment.ts`, but if you do
    // `ng build --env=prod` then `environment.prod.ts` will be used instead.
    // The list of which env maps to which file can be found in `.angular-cli.json`.

    export const environment = {
        production: config.settings.production,
        baseUrl: config.settings.baseUrl,
        loginUrl:config.settings.loginUrl,
        adminUrl: config.settings.adminUrl,
        userIdleMinutes: config.settings.userIdleMinutes,
        corePingIntervalSeconds: config.settings.corePingIntervalSeconds 
    };
```

Comment: The reason why I need it to be JSON is because the Octopus deployment tool can read JSON files and need the application to be configurable that way.  Had it been ts file,  I would have used environments itself and not created a separate config file

Comment: Then change your import in the enviroment file to the following:


import * as config from "../assets/config.json";